# Why does a tuple with more than one (all) None value evaulate to True?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, evaluation

Why does a tuple with

- a singe None element evaulate to (the correct and intended) False
- more than one (but all) None values evaulate to True?

Tuple with one None element:

```
>>> metadata = (None)
>>> if metadata:
...     print("True")
... else:
...     print("False")
...
False
```

Tuple with one or more None elements:

```
>>> metadata = (None, None)
>>> if metadata:
...     print("True")
... else:
...     print("False")
...
True
```

When there are more than one None elements in a tuple, I figured to use

```
>>> if all(metadata):
...     print("True")
... else:
...     print("False")
...
False
```

to get the results I want (which is, if all values in a tuple are None, I want it to realize its evaluation as None).

When a tuple is evaulated, is its length actually considered for the evaluation, rather than a short circuit of it's values? What is the rationale behind such an implementation?

```
>>> len(metadata)
2
>>>
```

Comment: `(None)` isn’t a tuple…

Comment: @deceze, I agree; Mea Culpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `metadata` variable is not a tuple. It's value is `None`, that's why `if metadata` returns `False`.

```
metadata = (None)
if metadata:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
# False
```

This `metadata` variable is a tuple. It's not an empty tuple. So `if metadata` condition returns `True`.

```
metadata = (None, None)
if metadata:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
# True
```

If `metadata` tuple hadn't included an empty data or `None`, `all(metadata)` would have returned `True`. But in this case `all(metadata)` returns `False`.

```
if all(metadata):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
# False
```

**Quote from:** https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty). Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def all(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if not element:
>             return False
>     return True
> ```

So if `metadata` were an empty iterable, `all(metadata)` would have returned `True`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I reliazed after I posted that the one element tuple is actually not a tuple; classic symptom of sleeplessness! Your description including the other part was helpful. So, like I guessed, it does seem like the length of the tuple is actually taken for evaluation when the tuple itself is tested, given True is returned for an empty iterable.

Answer (score 0):

`metadata` in your first code snippet is not a tuple:

```
>>> metadata = (None)
>>> type(metadata)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

`metadata = (None)` is same as `metadata = None`. To make it a one element tuple, use a trailing comma:

```
metadata = (None,)
```

Now you see both one element and more elements tuples work the same way.

`if metadata:` is `False` for an empty tuple.

```
metadata = ()

if metadata:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")

# False
```

To return a `False` for a tuple with all `None` entries, you can do without an `if` construct like:

```
>>> not all(x == None for x in metadata)
```